# $\int_0^{\infty}x^n e^{-ax}dx$

Tags: definite-integrals, gamma-function

> How is the following formula proven?
> [image: Formula]

I tried to use the integral $f(x)g'(x) (g(x) = \text{gamma function)}$ but it doesn't work.

This formula is used in Planck function integral and I really need to understand it for my astrophysics class. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to use integration by parts. Indeed $\int_0^\infty x^{n+1}e^{-ax}\mathrm{d}x=\int_0^\infty fg'\mathrm{d}x$ with $f(x):=x^{n+1},\,g(x):=-\frac1ae^{-ax}$ sets up a useful recursion relation.

Comment: If you know about the gamma function already, then you can immediately just let $t=ax$ and get the result by calculating the effect of the variable substitution

Comment: @FShrike thanks alot i understand completely all this time I just needed a small variable substitution

Comment: Perhaps start with the definition of the Gamma function $\Gamma(n) = \int_0^\infty x^{n-1} e^{-x}\, dx $

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recall that

$$\Gamma(n)=\int_0^\infty x^{n-1}e^{-x}~\mathrm{d}x.$$

Now let $t=ax$, $\mathrm{d}t=a~\mathrm{d}x$ in your integral, which gives you that

$$\int_0^\infty x^ne^{-ax}~\mathrm{d}x=\int_0^\infty \left(\frac{t}{a}\right)^ne^{-t}\frac{1}{a}~\mathrm{d}t=\frac{1}{a^{n+1}}\int_0^\infty t^ne^{-t}~\mathrm{d}t=\frac{\Gamma(n+1)}{a^{n+1}}.$$